# Unhandled Exception with Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tree

I have no idea what's causing it. Can you guys help me? Since last time people complained because I should only post a MCVE instead of all the source code. I'll just post what (I think) is related to the problem. It's basically a Binary Search Tree, and the unhandled exception is related with the add method of the BST class.

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include "Button.h"

class Node
{
private:

    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Button nextPlay;
    bool used;

public:

    Node();
    Node(int k, int x, int y);

    void setLeft(Node* n);
    Node* getLeft();
    void setRight(Node* n);
    Node* getRight();
    Button getPlay();
    int getKey();
    void setUsed();
    bool getUsed();

};

#endif
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node()
{
    key = 0;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
    //nextPlay = NULL;
    used = false;
}

Node::Node(int k, int x, int y)
{
    key = k;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
    nextPlay.getPosition()->x = x;
    nextPlay.getPosition()->y = y;
    used = false;
}

void Node::setLeft(Node* n)
{
    left = n;
}

Node* Node::getLeft()
{
    return left;
}

void Node::setRight(Node* n)
{
    right = n;
}

Node* Node::getRight()
{
    return right;
}

Button Node::getPlay()
{
    return nextPlay;
}

int Node::getKey()
{
    return key;
}

void Node::setUsed()
{
    used = true;
}

bool Node::getUsed()
{
    return used;
}
```

BST.h

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include "Node.h"

class BST
{
private:

    Node* root;

    bool add(Node* n, int k, int x, int y);
    int remAll(Node* n);
    Button get(Node* n);

public:

    BST();
    ~BST();

    bool add(int k, int x, int y);
    int remAll();
    Button get();

};

#endif
```

BST.cpp

```
#include "BST.h"

BST::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
}

BST::~BST()
{
    remAll();
}

bool BST::add(Node* n, int k, int x, int y)
{
    bool success;
    if (n = NULL)
    {
        n = new Node(k, x, y);
        success = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (k == n->getKey())
        {
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (k < n->getKey())
            {
                Node* leftTree = n->getLeft();
                success = add(leftTree, k, x, y);
                n->setLeft(leftTree);
            }
            else
            {
                Node* rightTree = n->getRight();
                success = add(rightTree, k, x, y);
                n->setRight(rightTree);
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

int BST::remAll(Node* n)
{
    int number;
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        number = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        number = remAll(n->getLeft());
        number += remAll(n->getRight());
        delete n;
        number++;
    }
    return number;
}

Button BST::get(Node* n)
{
    if (n != NULL)
    {
        if (!n->getUsed())
        {
            n->setUsed();
            return n->getPlay();
        }
        else
        {
            Node* rightTree = n->getRight();
            if (rightTree != NULL)
            {
                return get(rightTree);
            }
            else
            {
                Node* leftTree = n->getLeft();
                if (leftTree != NULL)
                {
                    return get(leftTree);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool BST::add(int k, int x, int y)
{
    return add(root, k, x, y);
}

int BST::remAll()
{
    int number = remAll(root);
    root = NULL;
    return number;
}

Button BST::get()
{
    return get(root);
}
```

When I run the program the unhandled exception points to:

```
int Node::getKey()
{
    return key;
}
```

Which is used in the add method of BST.

Comment: Can paste the full error please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a note to an empty BST,  the execution will be:

```
bool BST::add(int k, int x, int y)
{
    return add(root, k, x, y);
}
```

As `root` is `NULL`, the following will happen in `add(root, k, x, y)`:

```
   bool success;
   if (n = NULL) {      // <=== OUCH !!! you set n to NULL if if wasn't 
       ...              // this is ignored because the condition is always NULL
   }
   else {               // so the else part is executed       
       if (k == n->getKey()) {  //  <======OUCH !!! remember n is NULL
```

So at this stage, because of the two errors (see OUCH comments above), you dereference a null pointer `n`.  This causes your segfault.

*Remark: Technically speaking, as `getKey()` is not virtual, that function might in fact get called with `this` being NULL, so that the segfault would be triggered only when `key` is accessed.  But this is implementation dependent.*

## How to solve it ?

First, correct the case where the node is NULL:

```
if (n == NULL)   // == instead of =
```

But this is not sufficient.  Your recursive algorithm expects that the following statement modifies a pointer in the tree.  Unfortunately, in reality it only modifies only a local pointer variable, and let the tree as it was:

```
    n = new Node(k, x, y);   // store the newly created node, but... n is local
```

Your approach would only work if `n` would be a reference to the original pointer in the tree.  You can achieve this by changing the signature of the function:

```
bool BST::add(Node*& n, int k, int x, int y)  // pass n by reference
```

Comment: I'm retarded, thanks for your help, it's kinda working.
It's funny how the lack of two characters were making my life miserable, mostly the first one being just a "typo" mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be when create the node. Your are passing the pointer by value in `add` method instead of by reference. The function signature should be `bool BST::add(Node*& n, int k, int x, int y)`. Also change `n = NULL` to `n == NULL` to compare instead of asign.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

An often-suggested method to avoid errors of the kind

```
if (n = NULL) {
```

is to try switch your style to do

```
if (NULL == n) {
```

This should result in the compiler giving you an error. The L.H.S operand is no longer an l-value and becomes illegal for '=', but, not for '==', preventing you from accidentally doing this. I have done this mistake a couple of times early on in my career and switched permanently.